# functions not returning values that a user enters

Tags: c++, function

I AM working on this program for an assignment, so I don't want the answer...just a push in the right direction.

I have written a program in which a user will input a 3-digit ID (required) and an amout of KWh used for the month. After that criteria has been entered, it will print out a short summary + the charges for that month per user. And this is enclosed in a loop to ask if there are any more IDs to be entered.

Below is my opening code and loop structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
string get_user_ID();
int get_cust_kwh();
string display_cust_data();

int main()
{
string userID;
int userKWH;
char answer;

while ((answer !='N')&&(answer !='n')){
    userID = get_user_ID();
    userKWH =get_cust_kwh();

    display_cust_data();

    cout << "\n\nWould you like to add another utility ID? : (Y or N)";
    cin >> answer;

    }
}

system("pause")
return 0;
```

I can get the loop to function correctly, but my functions don't seem to be returning the values that the user enters. As I am new to functions, I am sure it's some silly mistake, but one that has been driving me crazy. Here are the functions:

```
**********function definitions**********
string get_user_ID(){
    string usrID;
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter in your 3-digit utility ID: ";
    cin >> usrID;
    return usrID;
}

int get_cust_kwh(){
    int usrKWHs;
    cout << "Please enter the total KWH used for the month: ";
     cin >> usrKWHs;
    return usrKWHs;
}

string display_cust_data(){
    string usrID;
    int usrKWHs;
    double userCharge;

    cout << "\n\nUSER ID        KWHours     Charge($)\n";
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << usrID << "            " << usrKWHs << "           " << userCharge << endl;
   }
```

I'm thinking something to do with the way the variables in the functions are used.

Thanks for any pushes you can give!

Comment: tip: step through with a debugger.  The problem should be obvious as you step into the function with the bug.

Comment: Your last function has a return type `string` but has no `return` statement. And all of the variables inside are local, you need to pass the variables scoped in main.

Comment: Generally you don't want to do `cin >> <someVar>`, cin doesn't do typechecking or anything and that type of call can cause strangeness. Also, you aren't printing the vars you initialized. You're printing uninitialized variables you just created. Take a good look at your last method.

Comment: it's usually a good idea to check the status of the stream after reading a variable, and throwing an exception if it's bad.  `if(!cin) {throw std::runtime_error("SOMETHING IS WRONG");}`  This might be beyond what you've learned so far, but it is important to know later.

Comment: I can tell which answer was given by someone who has been a teacher. :)

Comment: @ProgNewbie: New to functions. The concept you need to read up on is function parameters (aka function arguments). These are how you pass information in your main function to the other functions you write. It doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `display_cust_data()` doesn't know about variables in main function scope. What you are printing is just the local variables which has garbage values.

```
string display_cust_data(){
    string usrID;  // This is a different variable and is not equivalent to the 
                   // variable in main.
```

Also why the function's return type is `string` ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your display_cust_data. How does it get any information about what to display?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a way to pass the user input variables to your display function. The variables you have in the `display_cust_data()` function are newly created there and are not the same as the variables you have in your while loop in your `main()` function. All of the variables you display in that function are uninitialised and so you have no idea what their values will actually be. Consider adding arguments to the function so that when you call it you can pass the user input variables to it so that you can display the values you want to display.